# weird error in running plugin

Tags: java, plugins, applet

Though i don't think this question can be asked here, just for you guys help i'm asking. I trade in Forex and there i get an option where i can see charts, and there is a java plugin for viewing these charts, when i run it, it is giving me the below error.

```
com.netdania.appletchart.AppletChart.class->ClassNotFoundException.
```

and the details are as below.

```
Java Plug-in 10.51.2.13
Using JRE version 1.7.0_51-b13 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\u0138039
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
```

really unable to know how to fix it. My Java version is uptodate. and in IE even this is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is actually caused by a corrupt install of Java within the registry.  In order to repair this you first must uninstall Java then sort through ALL of the registry keys for any lingering keys and delete them all  (they should all be in the HKLM\Software string),  then reinstall Java.  It will take a lot of slogging through the registry to find all of the keys, but that wound up being how I had to fix this one.